# How to loop through checkboxes on dynamically created userform?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, checkbox, userform

I'm trying to utilize a dynamically created userform and based on what boxes are check, gray out certain cells.

As background, this is for an injection molding facility. QA sets up the cavity numbers that are running. This dynamic userform creates checkboxes based on the cavity numbers that are input on the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim col         As Long
Dim row         As Long
Dim lcol        As Long
Dim i           As Long
Dim j           As Long
Dim chkBox      As MsForms.CheckBox
Dim l           As MsForms.Frame
Dim t           As MsForms.Label

Set l = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "cavz", True)
    l.Caption = "BLOCKED CAVITIES"
    l.Height = 195
Set t = l.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "mark")
    t.Caption = "Mark all cavities that are currently blocked:"
    t.Width = 175
    t.Top = 10

col = 2 'Set your column index here
row = 8
lcol = 17
j = 1

For i = col To lcol
Set chkBox = l.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox_" & i)
If Worksheets("QA").Cells(row, i).Value <> "" Then
    chkBox.Caption = Worksheets("QA").Cells(row, i).Value
ElseIf Worksheets("QA").Cells(row, i).Value = "" Then
    GoTo 10
End If
If i <= 9 Then
    'MsgBox "i = " & i
    chkBox.Left = 5
    chkBox.Top = 5 + ((i - 1) * 20)
ElseIf i > 9 Then
    j = j + 1
    'MsgBox "j = " & j
    chkBox.Left = 100
    chkBox.Top = 5 + ((j - 1) * 20)
End If
10
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim x As Control
Dim cavz As MsForms.Frame

For Each x In cavz.Controls
If x.Value = True Then
    If x.Value = Range("B8") Then
        Range("B8:B14").Select
        Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 16
    End If
End If
Next x

End Sub
```

I started out doing one thing, and somehow this is what my code turned into. It's not the neatest code, but I would still consider myself a novice at this. Plus, this is the first time I couldn't find the answer on my own and thus my first time asking for help. So, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

***UPDATE***
This is great! Thank you Don. However, I do have a follow up question. Perhaps I've been banging my head against this for too long, but I cannot think of a more efficient way to do this. Here is what I'm now doing:

```
For i = 2 To 17
Set ctl = Controls.Item("CheckBox_" & i)
    If ctl = True Then
        If i = 2 Then
            Range(Cells(j, c), Cells(m, c)).Select
            Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 16
            Range(Cells(k, c), Cells(m, c)).Select
            With Selection
                .Merge
                Cells(k, c) = "BLOCKED"
                .Orientation = 90
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
        End If
Next i
```

etc

I'm in the process of writing if i = 1 through 17, but I feel like there's a more efficient way and I just can't crack it.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do in the follow up.

Comment: This will select the cells and change their color & add text "BLOCKED" if they are selected as blocked on the userform. I have it working with the 16 if statements, I was just curious if there was a better/more efficient way.

Comment: I don't see a reason for if statements. Figure out what changes in each case and use your loop to set the increment values of c, m, j, and k each time.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through them by name the same way you created them.

```
Dim ctl As Control

For i = 2 To 17
    Set ctl = Controls.Item("CheckBox_" & i)    
Next 'i
```

Also, I would create module level constants for the initial values of col, lcol, etc. and reuse those in both routines.

Comment: Hi Don! Thanks for this. I just added an update to my original question and wanted to see if you had any suggestions. Thanks again!